# Using Vue to filter dom objects

Tags: django, vue.js, vuejs2, django-templates

I have a list of items that are rendered on the server by Django. Them with the Django template language to render a list. The list is the list of dom objects.

On that item in the list, I have two data attributes that are text strings. What I want to do is use Vue to filter the list based on those attributes. What I was doing was using `v-if` to display items based on what was selected from two lists that contained matching data variables to the data-attributes.

The problem that I'm running into is, I can only get a two-part filter. So, I can only get this to work if I filter the first one thing and then the other. What I want to happen is filter the list by whatever dropdown is selected first and then further refined by the second one.

So, my question is, should I recreate the list in Vue Data components and then filter them or am I thinking about the `v-if` wrong?

Here' my dom object with the `v-if`:

```
<div class="page" data-example-1="{{ product.value.example-1 }}" data-example-2="{{ product.value.example-2 }}" v-if="example-1 === '{{ product.value.example-1 }}' && example-2 === '{{ product.value.example-2 }}'">
  <h3 class="is-title is-3">{{ product.value.title }}</h3>
  <p class="is-size-7">Loc: <strong>{{ product.value.example-1|title }}</strong> | Lang: <strong>{{ product.value.example-2|title }}</strong></p>
</div>
```

I realize right now I'm using the `&&` operator, but I'm not sure how else to think about this. As you can see, the `data-example-1` and `data-example-2` are not being used at the moment.

Suggestions welcome.

Comment: So vue actually has this built in and its called [filters](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html) and I think this is what you are looking for I think v-if is too limited for this scenario. IF this is what you are looking for let me know and i can provide some psuedo code ifneeded.

Comment: are you using array and v-for? if so you could use computed to filter the data then loop through the computed data

Comment: why not in a function which is referred by `v-if`?